# How to exclude rows with date range overlaps

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Postgresql - Data is in the following format

I am currently using the following SQL to get me all the booking dates set for a property

However, in a single day, when a user changes booking dates for a property several times then multiple entries are created which inflate the aggregate result.

Can I apply `if-else` logic to overlapping booking_dates (highlighted in red and yellow) to pick only the booking dates with max (updated_at)(highlighted in yellow)?

For example, red and yellow rows have overlapping booking dates. If I applied the following SQL then my sum will be incorrect. So, I only need to consider the booking dates when updated_at is max.

```
WITH X AS (SELECT distinct booking_end_date, booking_start_date, P_id
FROM booking)
SELECT sum(X.booking_end_date-X.booking_start_date) as Available, X.P_id
from X
group by X.P_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` to get the last entry for each day:

```
WITH X AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (pid, date_trunc('day', updated_at)) b.*
    FROM booking b
    ORDER BY pid, date_trunc('day', updated_at), updated_at desc
   )
select sum(X.booking_end_date - X.booking_start_date) as Available,
       X.P_id
from X
group by X.P_id
```

Comment: This is helpful in eliminating multiples entries created on the same day. However, my problem is that the rows shown in red are invalid because 1. The booking dates overlap and 2. Since the latest update was made as shown in yellow on 6/5/2015 only that row booking_start_date and end_date in yellow should be considered.